# Странное поведение

Tags: linux, c, gcc, gtk, gtk3

Есть код:

```
void TranslateMX(char *str)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; j*k < 100;)
    {
        printf(" ");
        if( (j % 10) == 0.0f && j != 0){
            str[i] = '\n';
            j = 0;
            k++;
            i++;
        }else{
            str[i] = arr[k][j];
            i++;
            str[i] = '\t';
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    gtk_label_set_text (label, str);
}
```

Все работает но если удалить printf или передать ей(prinf) "" то при запуске ничего не работает:

```
*** Error in `./main': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001b6ae00 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f32501157e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7f325011de0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x82302)[0x7f3250120302]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(posix_memalign+0x11d)[0x7f3250124b6d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x66236)[0x7f324d702236]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_slice_alloc+0x63a)[0x7f324d702f2a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0xb30a)[0x7f325068f30a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0xb3c6)[0x7f325068f3c6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x2c560)[0x7f32506b0560]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x2f59b)[0x7f32506b359b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_add_interface_static+0xc0)[0x7f32506b7820]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_widget_get_type+0x12e)[0x7f3250c27fde]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_misc_get_type+0x3d)[0x7f32509947ad]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_label_get_type+0x6c)[0x7f3250ad1edc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_label_set_text+0x11)[0x7f3250ad4241]
./main[0x40115e]
./main[0x400c43]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f32500be830]
./main[0x400b29]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 262725                             /home/mxd/Документы/C/GTK+/main
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:09 262725                             /home/mxd/Документы/C/GTK+/main
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 262725                             /home/mxd/Документы/C/GTK+/main
01b47000-01b89000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f3240000000-7f3240021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3240021000-7f3244000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3246f0c000-7f3246f13000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2376691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburcu-bp.so.4.0.0
7f3246f13000-7f3247112000 ---p 00007000 08:08 2376691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburcu-bp.so.4.0.0
7f3247112000-7f3247113000 r--p 00006000 08:08 2376691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburcu-bp.so.4.0.0
7f3247113000-7f3247114000 rw-p 00007000 08:08 2376691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburcu-bp.so.4.0.0
7f3247114000-7f324711d000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2376708                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblttng-ust-tracepoint.so.0.0.0
7f324711d000-7f324731d000 ---p 00009000 08:08 2376708                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblttng-ust-tracepoint.so.0.0.0
7f324731d000-7f324731e000 r--p 00009000 08:08 2376708                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblttng-ust-tracepoint.so.0.0.0
7f324731e000-7f324731f000 rw-p 0000a000 08:08 2376708                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblttng-ust-tracepoint.so.0.0.0
7f324731f000-7f324732f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f324732f000-7f3247341000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f3247341000-7f3247541000 ---p 00012000 08:08 3936780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f3247541000-7f3247542000 r--p 00012000 08:08 3936780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f3247542000-7f3247543000 rw-p 00013000 08:08 3936780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f3247543000-7f324761b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936644                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f324761b000-7f324781a000 ---p 000d8000 08:08 3936644                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f324781a000-7f324781b000 r--p 000d7000 08:08 3936644                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f324781b000-7f3247823000 rw-p 000d8000 08:08 3936644                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f3247823000-7f3247824000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3247824000-7f3247845000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936803                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f3247845000-7f3247a44000 ---p 00021000 08:08 3936803                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f3247a44000-7f3247a45000 r--p 00020000 08:08 3936803                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f3247a45000-7f3247a46000 rw-p 00021000 08:08 3936803                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f3247a46000-7f3247a5d000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367824                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7f3247a5d000-7f3247c5c000 ---p 00017000 08:08 2367824                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7f3247c5c000-7f3247c5d000 r--p 00016000 08:08 2367824                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7f3247c5d000-7f3247c5e000 rw-p 00017000 08:08 2367824                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7f3247c5e000-7f3247c64000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367930                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7f3247c64000-7f3247e64000 ---p 00006000 08:08 2367930                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7f3247e64000-7f3247e65000 r--p 00006000 08:08 2367930                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7f3247e65000-7f3247e66000 rw-p 00007000 08:08 2367930                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7f3247e66000-7f3247e89000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7f3247e89000-7f3248088000 ---p 00023000 08:08 2368234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7f3248088000-7f324808a000 r--p 00022000 08:08 2368234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7f324808a000-7f324808b000 rw-p 00024000 08:08 2368234                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7f324808b000-7f3248090000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367687                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f3248090000-7f324828f000 ---p 00005000 08:08 2367687                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f324828f000-7f3248290000 r--p 00004000 08:08 2367687                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f3248290000-7f3248291000 rw-p 00005000 08:08 2367687                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f3248291000-7f3248293000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f3248293000-7f3248493000 ---p 00002000 08:08 2367676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f3248493000-7f3248494000 r--p 00002000 08:08 2367676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f3248494000-7f3248495000 rw-p 00003000 08:08 2367676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f3248495000-7f32484ab000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936774                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f32484ab000-7f32486aa000 ---p 00016000 08:08 3936774                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f32486aa000-7f32486ab000 rw-p 00015000 08:08 3936774                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f32486ab000-7f324881d000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2361354                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f324881d000-7f3248a1d000 ---p 00172000 08:08 2361354                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f3248a1d000-7f3248a27000 r--p 00172000 08:08 2361354                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f3248a27000-7f3248a29000 rw-p 0017c000 08:08 2361354                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f3248a29000-7f3248a2d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3248a2d000-7f3248a5d000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368658                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f3248a5d000-7f3248c5c000 ---p 00030000 08:08 2368658                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f3248c5c000-7f3248c5d000 r--p 0002f000 08:08 2368658                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f3248c5d000-7f3248c5e000 rw-p 00030000 08:08 2368658                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f3248c5e000-7f3248c61000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367826                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f3248c61000-7f3248e60000 ---p 00003000 08:08 2367826                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f3248e60000-7f3248e61000 r--p 00002000 08:08 2367826                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f3248e61000-7f3248e62000 rw-p 00003000 08:08 2367826                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f3248e62000-7f3248ec0000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368481                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7f3248ec0000-7f32490bf000 ---p 0005e000 08:08 2368481                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7f32490bf000-7f32490c2000 r--p 0005d000 08:08 2368481                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7f32490c2000-7f32490c3000 rw-p 00060000 08:08 2368481                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7f32490c3000-7f32490f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368480                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7f32490f1000-7f32492f1000 ---p 0002e000 08:08 2368480                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7f32492f1000-7f32492f3000 r--p 0002e000 08:08 2368480                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7f32492f3000-7f32492f4000 rw-p 00030000 08:08 2368480                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7f32492f4000-7f3249362000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936865                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f3249362000-7f3249562000 ---p 0006e000 08:08 3936865                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f3249562000-7f3249563000 r--p 0006e000 08:08 3936865                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f3249563000-7f3249564000 rw-p 0006f000 08:08 3936865                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f3249564000-7f324957b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3934274                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f324957b000-7f324977b000 ---p 00017000 08:08 3934274                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f324977b000-7f324977c000 r--p 00017000 08:08 3934274                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f324977c000-7f324977d000 rw-p 00018000 08:08 3934274                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f324977d000-7f324977f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f324977f000-7f324979e000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f324979e000-7f324999d000 ---p 0001f000 08:08 3936894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f324999d000-7f324999e000 r--p 0001e000 08:08 3936894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f324999e000-7f324999f000 rw-p 0001f000 08:08 3936894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f324999f000-7f32499a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f32499a1000-7f32499c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936767                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f32499c7000-7f3249bc7000 ---p 00026000 08:08 3936767                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f3249bc7000-7f3249bc9000 r--p 00026000 08:08 3936767                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f3249bc9000-7f3249bca000 rw-p 00028000 08:08 3936767                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f3249bca000-7f3249bd2000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7f3249bd2000-7f3249dd1000 ---p 00008000 08:08 2368832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7f3249dd1000-7f3249dd2000 r--p 00007000 08:08 2368832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7f3249dd2000-7f3249dd3000 rw-p 00008000 08:08 2368832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7f3249dd3000-7f3249e2f000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2360709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7f3249e2f000-7f324a02f000 ---p 0005c000 08:08 2360709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7f324a02f000-7f324a030000 r--p 0005c000 08:08 2360709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7f324a030000-7f324a031000 rw-p 0005d000 08:08 2360709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7f324a031000-7f324a07b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3933046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f324a07b000-7f324a27b000 ---p 0004a000 08:08 3933046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f324a27b000-7f324a27c000 r--p 0004a000 08:08 3933046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f324a27c000-7f324a27d000 rw-p 0004b000 08:08 3933046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f324a27d000-7f324a2a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7f324a2a9000-7f324a4a8000 ---p 0002c000 08:08 2367788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7f324a4a8000-7f324a4ab000 r--p 0002b000 08:08 2367788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7f324a4ab000-7f324a4ac000 rw-p 0002e000 08:08 2367788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7f324a4ac000-7f324a4c5000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936927                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f324a4c5000-7f324a6c4000 ---p 00019000 08:08 3936927                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f324a6c4000-7f324a6c5000 r--p 00018000 08:08 3936927                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f324a6c5000-7f324a6c6000 rw-p 00019000 08:08 3936927                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f324a6c6000-7f324a6cf000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f324a6cf000-7f324a8ce000 ---p 00009000 08:08 2367709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f324a8ce000-7f324a8cf000 r--p 00008000 08:08 2367709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f324a8cf000-7f324a8d0000 rw-p 00009000 08:08 2367709                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f324a8d0000-7f324a8d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2369040                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7f324a8d8000-7f324aad8000 ---p 00008000 08:08 2369040                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7f324aad8000-7f324aad9000 r--p 00008000 08:08 2369040                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7f324aad9000-7f324aada000 rw-p 00009000 08:08 2369040                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7f324aada000-7f324aadc000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2369044                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7f324aadc000-7f324acdc000 ---p 00002000 08:08 2369044                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7f324acdc000-7f324acdd000 r--p 00002000 08:08 2369044                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7f324acdd000-7f324acde000 rw-p 00003000 08:08 2369044                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7f324acde000-7f324ad02000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7f324ad02000-7f324af01000 ---p 00024000 08:08 3936877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7f324af01000-7f324af02000 r--p 00023000 08:08 3936877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7f324af02000-7f324af03000 rw-p 00024000 08:08 3936877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
7f324af03000-7f324afa2000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368637                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7f324afa2000-7f324b1a2000 ---p 0009f000 08:08 2368637                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7f324b1a2000-7f324b1aa000 r--p 0009f000 08:08 2368637                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7f324b1aa000-7f324b1ab000 rw-p 000a7000 08:08 2368637                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7f324b1ab000-7f324b1cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2369054                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f324b1cc000-7f324b3cb000 ---p 00021000 08:08 2369054                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f324b3cb000-7f324b3cc000 r--p 00020000 08:08 2369054                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f324b3cc000-7f324b3cd000 rw-p 00021000 08:08 2369054                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f324b3cd000-7f324b471000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368107                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1
7f324b471000-7f324b670000 ---p 000a4000 08:08 2368107                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1
7f324b670000-7f324b676000 r--p 000a3000 08:08 2368107                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1
7f324b676000-7f324b677000 rw-p 000a9000 08:08 2368107                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1
7f324b677000-7f324b67a000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3934251                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f324b67a000-7f324b879000 ---p 00003000 08:08 3934251                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f324b879000-7f324b87a000 r--p 00002000 08:08 3934251                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f324b87a000-7f324b87b000 rw-p 00003000 08:08 3934251                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f324b87b000-7f324b882000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3934243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f324b882000-7f324ba81000 ---p 00007000 08:08 3934243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f324ba81000-7f324ba82000 r--p 00006000 08:08 3934243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f324ba82000-7f324ba83000 rw-p 00007000 08:08 3934243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f324ba83000-7f324ba94000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f324ba94000-7f324bc93000 ---p 00011000 08:08 2367689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f324bc93000-7f324bc94000 r--p 00010000 08:08 2367689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f324bc94000-7f324bc95000 rw-p 00011000 08:08 2367689                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f324bc95000-7f324bd10000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368479                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7f324bd10000-7f324bf10000 ---p 0007b000 08:08 2368479                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7f324bf10000-7f324bf15000 r--p 0007b000 08:08 2368479                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7f324bf15000-7f324bf16000 rw-p 00080000 08:08 2368479                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7f324bf16000-7f324bf22000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368946                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7f324bf22000-7f324c121000 ---p 0000c000 08:08 2368946                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7f324c121000-7f324c123000 r--p 0000b000 08:08 2368946                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7f324c123000-7f324c124000 rw-p 0000d000 08:08 2368946                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7f324c124000-7f324c125000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2364607                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7f324c125000-7f324c324000 ---p 00001000 08:08 2364607                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7f324c324000-7f324c325000 r--p 00000000 08:08 2364607                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7f324c325000-7f324c326000 rw-p 00001000 08:08 2364607                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7f324c326000-7f324c32a000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368948                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7f324c32a000-7f324c529000 ---p 00004000 08:08 2368948                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7f324c529000-7f324c52a000 r--p 00003000 08:08 2368948                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7f324c52a000-7f324c52e000 rw-p 00004000 08:08 2368948                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7f324c52e000-7f324c56b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2369058                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7f324c56b000-7f324c76a000 ---p 0003d000 08:08 2369058                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7f324c76a000-7f324c76c000 r--p 0003c000 08:08 2369058                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7f324c76c000-7f324c76d000 rw-p 0003e000 08:08 2369058                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7f324c76d000-7f324c76f000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367685                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f324c76f000-7f324c96e000 ---p 00002000 08:08 2367685                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f324c96e000-7f324c96f000 r--p 00001000 08:08 2367685                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f324c96f000-7f324c970000 rw-p 00002000 08:08 2367685                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f324c970000-7f324c972000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
7f324c972000-7f324cb71000 ---p 00002000 08:08 2367681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
7f324cb71000-7f324cb72000 r--p 00001000 08:08 2367681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
7f324cb72000-7f324cb73000 rw-p 00002000 08:08 2367681                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
7f324cb73000-7f324cb7c000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367683                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f324cb7c000-7f324cd7b000 ---p 00009000 08:08 2367683                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f324cd7b000-7f324cd7c000 r--p 00008000 08:08 2367683                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f324cd7c000-7f324cd7d000 rw-p 00009000 08:08 2367683                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f324cd7d000-7f324cd87000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7f324cd87000-7f324cf86000 ---p 0000a000 08:08 2367707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7f324cf86000-7f324cf87000 r--p 00009000 08:08 2367707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7f324cf87000-7f324cf88000 rw-p 0000a000 08:08 2367707                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
7f324cf88000-7f324cf8a000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2367699                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7f324cf8a000-7f324d189000 ---p 00002000 08:08 2367699                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7f324d189000-7f324d18a000 r--p 00001000 08:08 2367699                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7f324d18a000-7f324d18b000 rw-p 00002000 08:08 2367699                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
7f324d18b000-7f324d192000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2368059                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f324d192000-7f324d391000 ---p 00007000 08:08 2368059                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f324d391000-7f324d392000 r--p 00006000 08:08 2368059                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f324d392000-7f324d393000 rw-p 00007000 08:08 2368059                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f324d393000-7f324d49b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3934263                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f324d49b000-7f324d69a000 ---p 00108000 08:08 3934263                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f324d69a000-7f324d69b000 r--p 00107000 08:08 3934263                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f324d69b000-7f324d69c000 rw-p 00108000 08:08 3934263                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f324d69c000-7f324d7ab000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 3936778                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1
7f324d7ab000-7f324d9aa000 ---p 0010f000 08:08 3936778                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1
7f324d9aa000-7f324d9ab000 r--p 0010e000 08:08 3936778                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1
7f324d9ab000-7f324d9ac000 rw-p 0010f000 08:08 3936778                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1
```

/*Ну там далее далее.....(Нехватает символов)*/

```
7ffd6fc66000-7ffd6fc87000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd6fdd2000-7ffd6fdd4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd6fdd4000-7ffd6fdd6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Аварийный останов (сделан дамп памяти)
```

Вот arr.

```
char arr[10][10] = {
        { '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
        { '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0' },
        { '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1' },
        { '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0' },
        { '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1' },
        { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0' }
    };
```

Вот инициализация *str.

```
str = (char*)malloc( sizeof(*str) * 100 + 20);
```

Comment: Как создается `label` и чему равно `str`и `arr`  ?

Comment: `(j % 10) == 0.0f` - Вы серьезно? Но так как у Вас похоже линукс, запускайте свое приложение под valgrind и смотрите. Но более чем уверен, что там расстел памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim я в С пошел с C#, это мало о чем говорит но я не смотрел возвращаемое значение и не знал приведется ли тип если не совпадет, хотя изначально был 0, вернуть забыл.

Comment: @CGLike  Форматируйте ваш код.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow готов поклясться он был от отформатирован, ща исправлю

Comment: @CGLike даже в шарпе подобное - большая странность. процент - это остаток это очевидно, что он определен только для целых чисел. А Вы его сравнивниваете с вещественным.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, программа `indent` выручает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было: `str = (char*)malloc( sizeof(*str) * 100*2 + 20);`

Comment: Заметил когда правил вопрос(

Comment: Что означает это магическое число 20?

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/130318)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, 20? Ну, это же на всякий случай, вдруг "немного" ошибаемся с подсчетом байт. Но оказалось, что ошиблись весьма прилично (120 вместо необходимых 201).

Comment: @Harry это ответ а не доплнение.

Comment: @avp '\n' - 2 символа(на самом деле 1, просто я еще не понимал) * 10 - количество строк = 20.
А ошибка была в том что я выделял для 1 смвола память, но потом сделал, так что нужно было по 2 а память не выделял.

Answer (score 3):

Программа имеет неопределенное поведение, так как в данном предложении

```
str = (char*)malloc( sizeof(*str) * 100 + 20);
```

выделяется недостаточно памяти, чтобы разместить символы массива через знак табуляции или новой строки. Кроме того, я предполагаю, что нужно еще полученную строку дополнить символом завершающего нуля `'\0'`

Если я правильно понял, то вы могли бы функцию написать следующим образом

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

char * TranslateMX(const char(*a)[N])
{
    char *s = malloc(2 * N * N + 1 );
    const char *p = (const char *)a;

    size_t j = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N * N; i++)
    {
        s[j++] = p[i];
        s[j++] = (i + 1) % N == 0 ? '\n' : '\t';
    }

    s[j] = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char arr[N][N] = {
        { '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
        { '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0' },
        { '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1' },
        { '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0' },
        { '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' },
        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1' },
        { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0' }
    };

    char *s = TranslateMX(arr);

    // вместо printf, как в этой демонстрационной программе
    // надо будет использовать закомментированное предложение
    // gtk_label_set_text (label, str); 
    printf(s);

    free(s);
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
1       1       0       1       0       1       0       1       1       0
0       0       0       1       0       1       0       0       1       0
0       1       0       0       0       1       1       0       1       1
0       1       1       0       1       1       0       0       0       0
0       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
0       0       0       1       0       1       0       0       1       0
0       1       0       0       0       1       0       1       0       0
0       1       0       0       1       1       0       1       0       1
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
```